# Wamp server is not turning green after windows re-installation

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

My folks out there I have installed my wamp server in `E:\` drive and it was running very well but when I reinstalled my windows 10 and now when running the wamp server it is saying that  `none of 3 services running` and I searched a lot for the solution but didn't find any solution.

Please help me find the right solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution for this as I was digging up deeper into the solution I found it on the program itself.

to solve the issue run the wamp server and when it is showing on the status bar
it will show in `red` color as the services are not running.

Just right click on the Wamp Icon and then hover over the `tools` option and then new options will appear now click on the `Reinstall all the services` it will prompt you to allow apache on the firewall click on allow and boom now your wamp server will run correctly.